# Github for Windows unable to locate Git on my system when opening the command prompt

Tags: windows, git, github-desktop

I have Windows 10 (German) and installed Git for Windows 2.13.2 (64 bit) at "C:\Program Files\Git".

I installed Github for Windows 0.6.2 (64 bit), the desktop version.

I can pull changes from my git repositories on Github just fine.

However, when clicking on menu Repository/Open command prompt an error message shows up saying that Github for Windows was unable to locate Git on my system.

[image]

I don't want to open the command prompt without Git nor do I need to install Git because I already have. Nowhere in the settings of Github for Windows I can tell it where to find Git. Adding "C:\Program Files\Git" to the Windows PATH has no effect.

How can I make Github for Windows open the Git bash?

Comment: You probably need to add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to your path. Note the `\bin` at the end.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, that did the trick. My mistake.

Comment: Great! Answer added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Adding "C:\Program Files\Git" to the Windows PATH has no effect.

Git installations usually have a `bin` subdirectory containing the `.exe` files.

Add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to your path. Note the `\bin` at the end.